# Perfect hash function that weakly preserves leading zeros

Tags: hash, hashing

I need a perfect hash function that maps 2 integers into one integer twice the size (i.e. $(Int64, Int64) \rightarrow Int128$).

The function preserves sum of leading zero bits:

- $(0, 0) \rightarrow 0$ - good mapping, as each argument has $64$ leading zeros and that transformed into $128$ leading zeros of the output
- $(0, 0) \rightarrow 27$ - also good mapping, output `0x11011` still has $123$ leading zeros
- $(2^{30}, 2^{15}) \rightarrow 2^{43}$ - good mapping, sum of arguments zeros is $33 + 48 = 81$ which is close enough to output's $84$
- $(0, 0) \rightarrow 2^{50}$ - bad mapping, only $77$ zeros in the output
- $f(a,b) = a × b$  preserves zero sum well but is not a perfect hash function

1. It's fine if the function doesn't work well with a small subset of arguments: $1\%$ of all pairs violates weak zero sum preservation is acceptable, but the function still should be a perfect hash function.
2. The function should not use additional memory like lookup tables.
3. If $z(x)$ is the number of leading bits then zero sum is $N$-preserved if $| z(x) + z(y)  - z(f(x,y))| \leq N$, I'm looking for $N \leq 3$, but $N \leq 6$ are good enough.

Comment: How is $27$ a good mapping for $(0, 0)$ since it does not have $128$ leading zeros?

Comment: I don't need a precise zero sum preservation

Comment: This is very unclear what you consider good or bad. Please be more precise in your post.

Comment: added exact requirement

Comment: What is $\text{bsr}$ ?

Comment: "bit search reverse" = index of the most significant bit, I rewrote the expression for easier understanding

Comment: $f(a, b) = a + b$ does not preserve zero sum. $2^{64} + 2^{64}= 2^{65}$ has $63$ leading zeros, not $0$. Perhaps you meant $f(a, b) = a\times b$ (or $f(a, b) = (a + 1) \times (b + 1)$ in order not to be bothered by a $0$ case)?

Comment: @Nathaniel yeah, you're correct

Comment: @njuffa for Morton code $z(2^i) = i, z(0) = 0, z(f(2^i, 0)) = 2i$ which is bad.

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev In my tests, the 2D Morton code and other *pairing functions* (e.g. Szudzik, Rosenberg-Strong) provide less than 1% zero-sum violations for $|z(x) + z(y) - z(f(x,y))| \le 6$. What are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $S$ which enumerates pairs $\langle s,t \rangle$ of 64-bit strings, with the following ordering:

- If $z(s)+z(t) < z(s')+z(t')$, then $\langle s,t \rangle$ is listed before $\langle s',t' \rangle$.
- If $z(s)+z(t) = z(s')+z(t')$ and $z(s) < z(s')$, then $\langle s,t \rangle$ is listed before $\langle s',t' \rangle$.
- If $z(s)=z(s')$ and $z(t)=z(t')$ and the concatenation $s\, t$ comes lexicographically before the concatenation $s' \, t'$, then $\langle s,t \rangle$ is listed before $\langle s',t' \rangle$.

Consider the sequence $T$ which enumerates 128-bit strings $u$, with the following ordering:

- If $z(u) < z(u')$, then $u$ is listed before $u'$.
- If $z(u)=z(u')$ and $u$ comes lexicographically before $u'$, then $u$ is listed before $u'$.

Now consider the mapping that maps from a pair $\langle s,t \rangle$ to its index in $S$, call the result $i$, then finds the $i$th item in $T$, and outputs the result.  This then is a perfect hash function, and I believe it satisfies your desired property.  Moreover, it is possible to compute both mappings (i.e., the ranking in $S$ and unranking in $T$) fairly efficiently.  Therefore, the hash function can be computed fairly efficiently.